# Convert "Linq to EF" to "Linq to Sql" in .NET

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have created a project using Linq to Entity Framework. But I have read that Linq to Sql is faster than EF. So Can I convert my project from Linq to EF to Linq to Sql?

Comment: Then why not use ADO .NET? It's the *fastest!* It's also worth mentioning that Entity Framework is the future; MS is no longer investing in LINQ to SQL although I don't believe it's officially deprecated or dropped support yet.

Comment: Just as Yuck, I would advice going back to LINQ to SQL, since MS is only maintaining LINQ to SQL and not adding new features (even not all bugs are being fixed). You can expect EF to beecome faster and better in the coming years, while L2S will not change. I do love L2S and is still has some features that even the latest EF release lacks, but for new projects, please do use EF. And Have you tested if EF is too slow for you? Moving to L2S seems like premature optimization to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "Linq to Sql is faster than EF" is a generally true statement. If the database communication poses performance problems, I'd first start investigating the SQL side to see if the way data is stored/queried can be improved (for example, add indexes if necessary).

Otherwise the effort of translating the project might not pay off.

Comment: I've seen L2S produce better SQL queries that run faster on SQL Server (especially when the queries get very big and complex) and the Expression tree to SQL translation process is faster. Still I agree that switching to LINQ to SQL is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

For long term maintainability reasons, you probably don't want to go from EF to Linq2SQL, because Microsoft have effectively abandoned new development work on Linq2SQL, having folded the project into EF from .NET 4 onwards. It's not worth the effort trying to convert onto something that's less modern and less actively developed just to potentially see some unsubstantiated claims of performance gains.